# Adding Name to Magento 2 SMTP Email

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

My system mails (such as new order emails) are coming from example@server.example.com (only the address; without name). But i want to see the 'from' section as like 'Example.com' in inbox..

** It's not about **Configuration > Store Email Addresses** or **Sales > Sales Email** sections. Everthing is ok there; all addresses have a name.

Do you have any idea? How can i add NAME to stmp address with server files, or is there any other options?

Comment: Hello @erererer
Are you using SMTP mail extension of Magento 2?

Comment: no.. should i? (actually, i'm not sure if the system sending smtp or not.. the only thing i know is, even magento configuration is okt, the system is sending system emails such as order/new account etc without name)